# RESTful Web Service with Jersey and Apache Shiro

Tags: java, post, jersey, shiro

My first attempt at developing a simple authentication based REST services. I am trying to develop a RESTful web application using Jersey on Tomcat 8. I am using Apache Shiro for session management and authorization. Only HTTPS is supported.
All services require authentication, neither guest nor anonymous access is allowed. The request can be authenticated two ways.

1. If the user belongs to the list of users in web application, then the user logs in from a Web browser and Shiro simply validates if the current user is logged in and allows request to proceed. This is for the custom UI provided by the application itself.
2. If the request is from third party application, the username/password token are passed into the HTTP header authorization field for every service request. The users are managed by third party app and the app uses a common username/password for its users to access the web service. Such common users are prevented from logging in.

All service requests are filtered (web.xml):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.unisys.cpf.ffm.filter.AuthenticationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>`enter code here`
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `AuthenticationFilter` class implements `ContainerRequestFilter` for authentication:

```
@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest cr) {
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        //User is not logged in so get the authorization from header and authenticate
        String auth = cr.getHeaderValue("authorization");
        //Do Shiro authentication here.
    }
    return cr;
}
```

I have a web service which accepts form parameters and creates a resource. The Form parameters are dynamic based on what user selects. So I cannot use @FormParam to get all the parameters. Also there may be more contents to form as new features are added so I do not want to touch the Service again for each new/removed parameter.

I am using the Chrome Advanced REST Client plugin to simulate third party requests. Any browser is fine for the first scenario (logged in user).
Now I know just two ways of accessing the form parameters.

First method is to use `MultivaluedMap`.

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
public String createResource(MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters) {
    System.out.println("Name of the resource: " + parameters.getFirst("resourceName"));
}
```

But trying to get the parameters using `MultivaluedMap` works only when a logged in  user submits the form. If I submit from REST Client plugin the same form values, then all parameters return null.

Second method is to use `@Context HttpServletRequest`

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
public String createResource(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Name of the resource: " + request.getParameter("resourceName"));
}
```

This works for REST Client but does not work if a logged in user submits form. All request.getParameter return null.

If anybody knows how to fix the problem or better way to do authentication, then please let me know.